# Random Image from Flickr

Tags: python, python-3.x, flickr

How do you get Flickr random Images using the API and Python?

I used the following Flickr API:

```
flickr.photos.search(text,page,per_page,extras)
# where:
#       text = "flower" (also with other words the results are very disappointing about the randomness)
#       per_page = 1 (I have set 1 Image per page)
#       page = In the vast majority of cases, the number of pages found per word exceeds 100000. Therefore I set a random number between 1 and 100000
#       extras = "url_sq,url_t,url_s,url_q,url_m,url_n,url_z,url_c,url_l,url_o"
```

When I launch my application, which displays an Image every 20 seconds, the results are very very disappointing, in the sense that, about every 20 Images displayed, 16 are always the same Image.
Below the entire code:

```
def update_flickrImage(self):

    FLICKR_PUBLIC = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    FLICKR_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
    flickr = FlickrAPI(FLICKR_PUBLIC,FLICKR_SECRET,format='parsed-json')
    random.seed()
    rand_page = random.randrange(1,100000,1)
    extras = 'url_sq,url_t,url_s,url_q,url_m,url_n,url_z,url_c,url_l,url_o'

    cats = flickr.photos.search(text="flower", page=rand_page, per_page=1, extras=extras)

    photos = cats['photos']

    pprint(photos)
    print("Page: ",rand_page)

    for image in photos['photo']:
        self.title = image['title']
        try:
            url = image['url_o']
            width = image['width_o']
            height = image['height_o']
        except:
            try:
                url = image['url_l']
                width = image['width_l']
                height = image['height_l']
            except:
                try:
                    url = image['url_c']
                    width = image['width_c']
                    height = image['height_c']
                except:
                    pass
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        self.pic = r.content
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code as close I could.  When I ran the test on 100 calls, I only got back 3 different links.

When I reduced the number to 4000 in the randrange function, I got 98 unique URLs out of 100.  The whole code is below (with my public and secret commented out):

```
import flickrapi as fa
import random 
# import pprint as pp
import time as ti

def update_flickrImage(self):
    FLICKR_PUBLIC = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    FLICKR_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    
    flickr = fa.FlickrAPI(FLICKR_PUBLIC,FLICKR_SECRET,format='parsed-json')
    
    random.seed()
    rand_page = random.randrange(1,4000,1)
    
    extras = 'url_sq,url_t,url_s,url_q,url_m,url_n,url_z,url_c,url_l,url_o'
    
    cats = flickr.photos.search(text="flower", 
                                page=rand_page, 
                                per_page=1, 
                                extras=extras)
    photos = cats['photos']
    
   # pp.pprint(photos)
    print("Page: ",rand_page)
     
    for image in photos['photo']:
        title = image['title']
        try:
            url = image['url_o']
            width = image['width_o']
            height = image['height_o']
        except:
            try:
                url = image['url_l']
                width = image['width_l']
                height = image['height_l']
            except:
                try:
                    url = image['url_c']
                    width = image['width_c']
                    height = image['height_c']
                except:
                    pass

    self['title'] = title
    self['url'] = url
    self['width'] = width
    self['height'] = height
    
    return url 
    
imgobj = {'title':'A','url':'https','width':'0','height':'0'}

for i in range(100):
    imgurl = update_flickrImage(imgobj)
    print( imgurl)
    ti.sleep(2)
```

Flickr search API has a limit of 4000 records returned per [search query](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html).

In my Flickr [account](https://www.flickr.com/photos/157919153@N05/) I have over 13,000 photos.  I can download 100 at a time for up to 1400 pages when I need to make a local searchable database in MySQL.  I do most of my Flickr work with PHP.

Yeah, you have to play with it. A search for "flower" returns 295,805 pages.  That's too much.

Also in my version of your code, I had to comment out the pretty print.  Title would blow it up with certain UTF characters.  I just wanted to see unique URLs.